# How to raise a number to an absolute value of another number in C#?

Tags: c#, math, pow, absolute-value

My problem is that I need to write a complex mathematical equation which has me raise `x` to the power of `|y|`, both numbers entered by user. I've tried using the code below, but it produces a `CS7036` error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Math.Pow(double, double)'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x,y,z,v;
        Console.Write("x=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
        Console.Write("y=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);
        Console.Write("z=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out z);
        v=(1+Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x+y)))/
            Math.Abs(x-2*y/(1+x*x*y*y))*Math.Pow(x,Math.Abs(y))+
            Math.Pow(Math.Cos(Math.Atan(1/z)),2);
        Console.Write("v="+v);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that programmers are human beings, and as human beings, the error _message_ is a lot more meaningful to us than the error _code_. As it stands, I have to use Google to find out what C7036 is, even though I may have seen it many times and know the exact solution. Please give the _full_ error message.

Comment: Also, please can you provide an [mcve] because it [works fine](http://rextester.com/JZIMQ58145) for me and I can't get a CS7036 error.

Comment: You mean a CS7036 error. Screenshot please

Comment: CS7036 appears to be "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'x' of y". I really don't see how that even applies to the code provided by OP.

Comment: @John I'm not too sure about that.  Quite alot of people know what _404_ is.  I'm not too sure your paragraph is helpful

Comment: Googling for `c7036 c#` or `c7036 c# error` only produces a hit to this question. C# compiler error codes begin with CS. What error do you think he's getting? I think it's CS7036. I also suspect it's somewhere other than the posted code. Screenshot please

Comment: @MickyD Would I get away with arguing that that's an HTTP status code and not an error code?  It's true for C# that most people will be familiar with the error _messages_ but not the codes, I think.

Comment: You get Cnnnn code from msvc. Could it be that wrong compiler was given a .cs file as input.

Comment: sorry, y'all. formatting is tricky on mobile

Comment: Note that the `(21,23)` part of the error message is LINENUMBER,POSITION which points to the broken part of the code. Access Denied's answer seems to be correct :-)

Comment: Yes, please pay more attention to the error message and the line numbers.

Comment: @john so tell me (because I'm still intensely curious) how you so quickly found (and asserted that you've seen many times) what c#'s error c7036 is? And what is c7036, because I still don't know?

Comment: omg, i feel so stupid. sorry, everybody. the error was not where i thought it was. coding in mobile is a long way from perfect. thanks, y'all!

Comment: Where did I assert that I have seen it many times, @Caius? "may" is an important word in that sentence. And I found it by adding the missing S, and then searching for it on Stackoverflow to see what the corresponding message was.

Comment: @Sober Visual Studio will typically highlight problems like this for you (as shown in tymtam's screenshot). If it's at all possible, you might want to test your code in Visual Studio when you get an error. I understand that this might not be possible. Good luck with learning C# anyway  (assuming that's what you're using SoloLearn for) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

(After the OP posted the code)

### Code

```
        double x,y,z,v;
        Console.Write("x=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
        Console.Write("y=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);
        Console.Write("z=");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out z);
        v=(1+Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x+y)))/
        Math.Abs(x-2*y/(1+x*x*y*y))*Math.Pow(x,Math.Abs(y))+
        Math.Pow(Math.Cos(Math.Atan(1/z)),2);
        Console.Write("v="+v);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

### Error

[image]

Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Math.Pow(double, double)'

### Problem

You are calling Math.Pow() with just one parameter: `Math.Sin(x + y)` and it requires two parameters.

### Solution

Check the formula and call the `Math.Pow` with two parameters, i.e.:

```
Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x + y), something_here )
```

---

## Original answer (before OP added the code and error description)

I'm not sure what C7036 is but this snippet outputs `8`:

```
        var x = 2;
        var y = 3;
        var number = Math.Pow(x, Math.Abs(y));
        Console.Write(number);
```

In this example x and y are `int`s and number is of type `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify second parameter to your Pow:

Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x + y),**SECOND**)

in

```
v = (1 + Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x + y))) / 
...
```

Comment: The OP gave the wrong line of code, the error was one line above. (since has been edited) This is the correct line and the solution is correct.